# joomla - undefined variables: slides in

Tags: joomla, joomla-template

Im new to Joomla. I managed install xampp and joomla in my local. I tried to install templates and it working fine but throwing an error as per image below. Please help. Thanks[image: Error]

Comment: Its only a notice and it means your variable is not initialized with a value, Notices are good under development process, but once you are finished you can hide/turn off those notices/error.

Comment: what u mean development process....?

Comment: site development process

Comment: Go to your admin backend->site->Global Configuration->Server. Under "Server Settings" tab change "Error Reporting" settings according to your requirement.

Comment: please put as answer...i will mark as answered..it working fine now..

Comment: Posted as answer..and thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its only a notice and it means your variable is not initialized with a value, Notices are good under development process, but once you are finished you can hide/turn off those notices/error.

> Go to your admin backend->site->Global Configuration->Server. Under
>   "Server Settings" tab change "Error Reporting" settings according to
>   your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Great tip, problem solved!

Go to your `admin backend > site > Global Configuration > Server`. Under `Server Settings` tab change `Error Reporting` settings according to your requirement.